# gnuplot legend overlaps graph

Tags: graph, gnuplot

Essentially, the problem that I am experiencing is that the legend overlaps the gnuplot graph that I am trying to plot as illustrated in the following diagram.

[image: Timings]

Following is the command that I am using to plot the data.

```
> set log y
> plot "datafile1.txt" using 2:4 with lines,
  "datafile1.txt" using 2:6 with lines,
  "datafile2.txt" using 2:4 with lines,
  "datafile2.txt" using 2:6 with lines
```

Following is a portion of the data file 1 I am using to plot the data.

```
Dimension:  259 Timing: 36111 seconds,  9 seconds
Dimension:  260 Timing: 37860 seconds,  9 seconds
Dimension:  261 Timing: 39477 seconds,  6 seconds
Dimension:  262 Timing: 41215 seconds,  5 seconds
Dimension:  263 Timing: 41827 seconds,  5 seconds
Dimension:  264 Timing: 42738 seconds,  11 seconds
Dimension:  265 Timing: 42972 seconds,  14 seconds
Dimension:  266 Timing: 44138 seconds,  10 seconds
Dimension:  267 Timing: 45210 seconds,  11 seconds
Dimension:  268 Timing: 46508 seconds,  9 seconds
Dimension:  269 Timing: 51120 seconds,  15 seconds
Dimension:  270 Timing: 49352 seconds,  6 seconds
Dimension:  271 Timing: 50456 seconds,  9 seconds
Dimension:  272 Timing: 52379 seconds,  16 seconds
Dimension:  273 Timing: 52354 seconds,  16 seconds
```

Following is a portion of the data file 2 I am using to plot the data.

```
Dimension:  269 Timing: 32507 seconds,  2 seconds
Dimension:  270 Timing: 33064 seconds,  4 seconds
Dimension:  271 Timing: 33590 seconds,  6 seconds
Dimension:  272 Timing: 33703 seconds,  3 seconds
Dimension:  273 Timing: 34616 seconds,  3 seconds
Dimension:  274 Timing: 36113 seconds,  4 seconds
Dimension:  275 Timing: 36477 seconds,  4 seconds
Dimension:  276 Timing: 37000 seconds,  2 seconds
Dimension:  277 Timing: 37872 seconds,  3 seconds
Dimension:  278 Timing: 42290 seconds,  6 seconds
Dimension:  279 Timing: 39862 seconds,  7 seconds
Dimension:  280 Timing: 40184 seconds,  7 seconds
Dimension:  281 Timing: 41229 seconds,  4 seconds
Dimension:  282 Timing: 43221 seconds,  3 seconds
Dimension:  283 Timing: 42706 seconds,  7 seconds
```

Any help or advice on how to overcome this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

If you want to turn it off altogether:

```
gnuplot> set nokey
```

If you want to move the legend, you can do this with

```
gnuplot> set key left top
```

to move it to the top left. If you want to give the lines more meaningful names in the legend, use the `title` keyword when generating the plot:

```
gnuplot> plot "datafile1.txt" using 2:4 with lines title "data",
....
```

Comment: Minor nit-pick -- Theses days `unset key` is probably preferred to `set nokey`.

Answer (score 32):

You could move the legend outside the plotting area, then they definitely wouldn't overlap:

```
gnuplot> set key outside
```

See here for many more options regarding the placement of the legend or key:
http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node192.html

Answer (score 14):

You can control location of the key by providing a set of coordinates:

```
set key at 25., 5000.
```

These values correspond to the data coordinate system. Alternatively, you can specify *graph* coordinates:

```
set key at graph 0.1, 0.9
```

(close to top-left position).

Comment: Thanks. I was getting nowhere with `at` here. I have no idea what the data coordinate system is, and the grammar of the `set key` command's use of the `first, second, polar, graph, screen, or character` keyword for the position threw me too; as did the use of small floating point numbers after `graph`. I had first expected a unit sizes similar to that of `set xtics offset`. Thanks again, I can work with this now.

Answer (score 6):

With the gnuplot version 5.2 and maybe later, you can use

```
set key at x, y
```

where `x` and `y` are the values for the x-axis and y-axis respectively